# Cardinality of intervals in solution of $\text{sin} \frac{1}{x}>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, elementary-set-theory

> Is the number of disjoint open intervals in the solution set of $\text{sin} \frac{1}{x}>0, 0<x<1$
> countably finite or uncountably infinite?

Use a change of variable. Let $y=\frac{1}{x}$:
$$\text{sin } y>0\implies y \in {(1,\pi) \cup (2\pi,3\pi) \cup ...}$$

Changing back to the original variable:
$$x \in {(1,\frac{1}{\pi}) \cup (\frac{1}{2\pi},\frac{1}{3\pi}) \cup ...}$$

which has cardinality based on rational numbers, and hence it is countably infinite.

Is this logic correct?
Note: This is a question I thought of.

Comment: This question is unclear. I believe it's "the number of disjoint open intervals".

Comment: Actually there is no such thing as "uncountable disjoint union of (nonempty) open intervals" in $\mathbb{R}$. Hint: every interval must contain a rational number. :)

Comment: @JianingSong y statements are likely not precise. But you will have to tell me how to make them precise. Also, do you mean "uncountable", or "uncountably infinite".

Comment: There is (of course) no need to say "uncountably infinite", because uncountable sets are not finite by definition. (Unless you are working with some deep set-theoretic context, then uncountable sets my not be [Dedekind-infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set), but this has nothing to do with our problem here.) I was referring in the comment to that, if a subset $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ can be written as the union of disjoint nonempty open intervals, then the number of such intervals must be countable (infinite or not).

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Liding Yao in comment,

If they asked for the number of disjoint open intervals in the solution set, then your approach shows that, cardinality of the set of such intervals is countably infinite.

On other hand, if they didn't asked for disjoint open intervals, then even the interval $(0,\frac{1}{π})$ can be expressed as uncountable union of singletons and we know that, every singleton set $\{a\}$ can be written as closed interval $[a, a]$. Hence the cardinality of the set of intervals in the solution set will be uncountable.